# Find not expanding variable

Tags: linux, find

I tried the following and it didn't work one bit.

```
image=.jpg,.png,.gif
find . -type f -iname "*$image"
```

Why? Does find not expand variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think find supports multiple extensions in that way. As per this [post by Alvin Alexander](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/an-example-of-use-unix-linux-find-command-locate-files-with-dif), you can do it like this:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" -o -name "*.gif" \)
```

With using the environment variable (assuming bash is the shell):

```
export image="-name *.jpg -o -name *.png -o -name *.gif"
find . -type f \( $image \)
```